# No of thread spikes with async, await, on a simple custom synchronization context

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I've written a simple Synchronization context, that does nothing, but just queues up the task to be executed on the same thread, one at a time.

But, it seems, when it hits an await, it fires up a new thread. 
The no. of threads doubled. I'm having difficulty understanding what's going on. Shouldn't this be running just 3 threads (1 thread for the app, and the other 2 for the GC, JIT)?

But it spiked instantly to 6.

**Update:** Running on x64 Release Build, on an Intel Core i5 with 2 cores - 4 threads.
Microsoft .NET 4.5 SDK, with optimization enabled.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ctx = new SyncContext();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctx);

            ctx.Post(o => Console.WriteLine("Hello"), null);

            ctx.Post(
                async o =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Entered async lambda.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        await Console.Out.WriteAsync("Async out.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Async post back.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("End async.");
                    }, null);

            ctx.Run();
        }
    }

    public class SyncContext : SynchronizationContext
    {
        private readonly Queue<Action> messageQueue = new Queue<Action>();

        private bool IsRunning { get; set; }

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsRunning = false;
            if (messageQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                lock (messageQueue)
                {
                    Monitor.Pulse(messageQueue);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            IsRunning = true;
            Action queuedAction;

            while (IsRunning)
            {
                lock (messageQueue)
                {
                    if (messageQueue.Count == 0)
                    {
                        // Make sure it wasn't stopped while contending for the lock.
                        if (IsRunning)
                        {
                            Monitor.Wait(messageQueue);
                        }

                        if (!IsRunning)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    queuedAction = messageQueue.Dequeue();
                }
                queuedAction();
                Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     When overridden in a derived class, dispatches an asynchronous message to a synchronization context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The <see cref="T:System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback" /> delegate to call.</param>
        /// <param name="state">The object passed to the delegate.</param>
        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            lock (messageQueue)
            {
                messageQueue.Enqueue(() => d(state));
                Monitor.Pulse(messageQueue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
3
Entered async lambda.

Async out.Async post back.

End async.
6
```

Comment: The number of threads (e.g., in the thread pool) is an implementation detail, and not one you need to worry about.

Comment: The Threadpool is never used here. So, Is there any way to make sure, extra threads aren't being started in the pool when you explicitly program to use a single thread?

Comment: Also, are all these threads, the threadpool threads? Is there any documentation to understand what these extra threads are?

Comment: There's no such thing as a single-threaded .NET application. The runtime always feels free to queue work to the thread pool, e.g., for console I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing has nothing to do with the synchronization context, as illustrated by the code below. I think the reason is that you're hitting the TPL task scheduler when you start an *asynchronous* task.

Most likely, the task scheduler (or some other TPL lazy initialization logic behind it) spins a number of threads for its own needs (or use `ThreadPool` threads for that matter). Apparently, this logic is smart enough to not do this for *synchronos* tasks, e.g., if you did `await Task.FromResult(true)` instead of `await Console.Out.WriteAsync()`.

Here's an example illustrating this using a custom awaiter:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task TestAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A, threads: {0}, thread: {1}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await new CustomAwaiter(async: false);
            Console.WriteLine("B, threads: {0}, thread: {1}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            Console.WriteLine("C, threads: {0}, thread: {1}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await new CustomAwaiter(async: true);
            Console.WriteLine("D, threads: {0}, thread: {1}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestAsync().Wait();
        }
    }

    public struct CustomAwaiter:
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion
    {
        readonly bool _async;

        public CustomAwaiter(bool async = true) { _async = async; }

        // awaiter methods
        public CustomAwaiter GetAwaiter() { return this; }

        public bool IsCompleted {get { return !_async; } }

        public void GetResult() { }

        // ICriticalNotifyCompletion
        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) { continuation(); }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A, threads: 3, thread: 1
B, threads: 3, thread: 1
C, threads: 3, thread: 1
D, threads: 6, thread: 1
```

As pointed out by @StephenCleary, the number of threads is really not something you should worry about here. Neither should you depend on this behaviour anyhow. If you're curious enough about what exactly going on there, dive into TPL implementation details using [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 0):

What output are you seeing? On my machine using VS2013 and .net 4.5 I get this output:

```
Hello
12
Entered async lambda.

Async out.Async post back.

End async.
12
```

In Linqpad, I get this:

```
Hello
28
Entered async lambda.
Async out.Async post back.
End async.
28
```

So in either case it doesn't look like there are any new threads started.

Comment: Updated, with the environment details. Sorry for the repeated edits. And are you sure, you're aren't running a debug build, or a hosting process bumping up your number of threads? 

I don't see why this simple console app should be running those many threads.

Comment: I was using it in Debug, in Release mode returned 13 threads both times

Comment: I guess, its an implementation detail that varies based on the systems, as Stephen Cleary commented. There's possibly no way to control it inside the runtime.